# How to merge the later half of an array into the first half one by one?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Suppose we have an array which contains 2m elements. we can divide the array into two parts, the first one and the later one. My question is how to insert the later part of the array into the first part one by one, for example the array

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

after merge we have the new array

```
{1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10}
```

I know some method to to this such as use another buffer to store the temp data, but it is required that the space complexity should be O(1).

My question is whether there exist an optimized method with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity?

Comment: This is answered on CS stack exchange [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/332/in-place-algorithm-for-interleaving-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 2 `temp` variables, suppose the array is `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

1: You start off by having 2 pointers, `temp1` at the starting and `temp2` at the halfway (at `6`)..

2: You store value of `temp1` i.e.`1` at first place in the array, and let `temp1` have the value of the second element, i.e.`2`

3: Similarly you store `temp2` i.e.`6` in the next place in the array, and let `temp2` have the next value, i.e. `7`..

Continue this until `temp1` reaches halfway and `temp2` reaches the end, and you would get the results as you desired..

Comment: It fails as soon as the second iteration, unless you better explicit how you move the pointers and store the values.

Comment: @fjardon: why will it fail in the second iteration?

Comment: It doesn't work because the values you copy from the second half would overwrite the values in the first half.

Comment: @interjay: you are interpreting the algorithm wrong, gimme a minute, will write the code and post..

Comment: Every step you need one temp variable more, therefore the space complexity is not O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, your best route is to simply define an iterator that does the addressing in the correct order, so you can leave all the data in place, and just change the order in which you address it.

If you can't do that, you obviously need an in-place merge. The cleanest explanation I've found of in-place merging is in an [article on Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-in-place-merge/240008783). Like most such papers/articles, this is written assuming that the intent is to do the merging as part of the implementation of a merge sort. As such, it's written in terms of finding the ranges of values that fit a sorting criteria. In your case, that part doesn't apply--you just want to merge the two halves with what you might think of as perfect interleaving, so you it's trivial to just select ranges based on placement rather than searching for the correct places based on comparing values. The operations for merge itself are done identically though.

## Bibliography

1. [Practical in-Place Merging](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f04/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf)
2. [Practical In-Place MergeSort](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B43F4E7B9963C5564C58204A7D1C746B?doi=10.1.1.22.8523&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
3. [Optimal and Efficient In-Place Merging](http://www.sofsem.cz/sofsem06/data/prezentace/23/A/Kim-OnOptimalandEfficientInPlaceMerging.ppt)
4. [Parallel in-place merge](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-in-place-merge/240008783)
5. [In-Place Merge-Sort Demystified](http://xinok.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/in-place-merge-sort-demystified-2/)